# Как сделать так, чтобы результат выводился в одну строку?

Tags: javascript, css, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.block2
{
    display: block;
    clear: both;
 float: right;
}
.block3
{
 white-space: pre;
 dispaly: block;
 clear: both;
 float: left;
}
.block1
{
 float: right;
}
dev
{
 widh: 10px;
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 5px solid navy;
}
h1
{
  text-align: center;
  color: #CC0000;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
h2
{
  text-align: center;
  color: #009933;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
}
body
{
 background-color: #FFCCCC;
}
</style>
<title>COTOMARKET</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var products = ["","Apple iPhone 6 Plus 16GB", "Apple iPhone 4S 8GB", "Apple iPhone 5s 32GB", 
"Doro Liberto 810", "Huawei Honor 7", "LG Neon 4G", "LG G45", 
"Microsoft Lumia 535", "Microsoft Lumia 640", "Nokia 108", "Samsung Galaxy J5", 
"Samsung Galaxy S5 Neo SM-G903F 16GB", "Samsung Galaxy S6 32GB", "Sony Xperia M4 Aqua"];
var prices = ["",799, 250, 600, 249, 399, 129, 349, 98, 139, 25, 195, 395, 599, 269];
var amount = ["",25,13,65,78,44,12,89,78,92,34,18,25,47,39]
var inv = [];

 function makeOptions()
{
 var i;
 for(i = 0; i < products.length; i++)
 {
  document.write("<option>" + products[i] + "</option>");
 }
}
 
function display()
{
 var index;
 index = document.getElementById("sel").selectedIndex;
 inv[index] = amount[index]*prices[index];
 if (index >= 0)
 {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<div class=\"block2\">" + products[index] + "</div>" + "<div class=\"block2\">Price :" + prices[index] + " </div>" + "<div class=\"block2\">Amount :" + amount[index] + "</div>" + "<div class=\"block2\">Inventory value :" + inv[index] + "</div>";
 }
 else 
 {
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
 }
 
}
function choise()
 {
  var out = "";
  var min = Number(document.getElementById("min").value);
  var max = Number(document.getElementById("max").value); 
   if (min>=max)
    {
     document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = "<br>Error! Min value >= Max value";
     return;
    }
   for(var i=1; i<=14; i++)
    {
     if ((prices[i]>min) && (prices[i]<max))
      {
      out += "<div class=\"block3\">" + products[i] + "</div>"  + "<div class=\"block3\">" + "Price: " + prices[i] + "</div>"; 
      document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = out;
      }
    }   
 }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1><dev>The BEST smartphone site ever!</dev></h1>
<h2>Made by Mr.David</h2>
Minimal price: <input type="text" id="min">
Maximal price: <input type="text" id="max"> <input type="button" value="Insert" onclick="choise()"> 
<div class="block1">All models: <select id="sel" onchange="display()">
 <script>
  makeOptions();
 </script>
</select></div>
<div id="result"></div><div id="output2"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Не могу понять как сделать так, чтобы результат, который получается после ввода минимального значения в первое поле(Например 200), максимального во второй(Например 700) и выбрать в списке выбора справа любое устройстово, выводился в одну строку. Перепробовал и `display: inline-block` и `float right/left` но ничего не получается. 
Нужно чтобы не было вот этого пространства
[image: Ненужное пространство]

Comment: Исправил, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Непонятно, как формат вывода Вам нужен, но пускай моя кофейная гуща подскажет формат: по каждой позиции {[модель] [цена]} на одной строчке.

CSS:

```
.clear
{
    clear: both;
}

.block3
{
    white-space: pre;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var out = "<div class='clear'></div>";
....
    out += "<div><div class=\"block3\">" + products[i] + "</div>"  + "<div class=\"block3\">" + " Price: " + prices[i] + "</div></div>";
....
```

Итог:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.block2
{
    display: block;
    clear: both;
 float: right;
}
.clear
{
 clear: both;
}
.block3
{
 white-space: pre;
 display: inline-block;
}
.block1
{
 float: right;
}
dev
{
 widh: 10px;
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 5px solid navy;
}
h1
{
  text-align: center;
  color: #CC0000;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
h2
{
  text-align: center;
  color: #009933;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
}
body
{
 background-color: #FFCCCC;
}
</style>
<title>COTOMARKET</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var products = ["","Apple iPhone 6 Plus 16GB", "Apple iPhone 4S 8GB", "Apple iPhone 5s 32GB", 
"Doro Liberto 810", "Huawei Honor 7", "LG Neon 4G", "LG G45", 
"Microsoft Lumia 535", "Microsoft Lumia 640", "Nokia 108", "Samsung Galaxy J5", 
"Samsung Galaxy S5 Neo SM-G903F 16GB", "Samsung Galaxy S6 32GB", "Sony Xperia M4 Aqua"];
var prices = ["",799, 250, 600, 249, 399, 129, 349, 98, 139, 25, 195, 395, 599, 269];
var amount = ["",25,13,65,78,44,12,89,78,92,34,18,25,47,39]
var inv = [];

 function makeOptions()
{
 var i;
 for(i = 0; i < products.length; i++)
 {
  document.write("<option>" + products[i] + "</option>");
 }
}
 
function display()
{
 var index;
 index = document.getElementById("sel").selectedIndex;
 inv[index] = amount[index]*prices[index];
 if (index >= 0)
 {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<div class=\"block2\">" + products[index] + "</div>" + "<div class=\"block2\">Price :" + prices[index] + " </div>" + "<div class=\"block2\">Amount :" + amount[index] + "</div>" + "<div class=\"block2\">Inventory value :" + inv[index] + "</div>";
 }
 else 
 {
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
 }
 
}
function choise()
 {
  var out = "<div class='clear'></div>";
  var min = Number(document.getElementById("min").value);
  var max = Number(document.getElementById("max").value); 
   if (min>=max)
    {
     document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = "<br>Error! Min value >= Max value";
     return;
    }
   for(var i=1; i<=14; i++)
    {
     if ((prices[i]>min) && (prices[i]<max))
      {
      out += "<div><div class=\"block3\">" + products[i] + "</div>"  + "<div class=\"block3\">" + " Price: " + prices[i] + "</div></div>"; 
      document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = out;
      }
    }   
 }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1><dev>The BEST smartphone site ever!</dev></h1>
<h2>Made by Mr.David</h2>
Minimal price: <input type="text" id="min">
Maximal price: <input type="text" id="max"> <input type="button" value="Insert" onclick="choise()"> 
<div class="block1">All models: <select id="sel" onchange="display()">
 <script>
  makeOptions();
 </script>
</select></div>
<div id="result"></div><div id="output2"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Я имел ввиду чтобы не было вот этого отступа  http://imgur.com/OBthryc

Comment: @DavidArutiunian, теперь понятнее, я просто плохо гадаю на кофейной гуще, так как кофе не пью. Перед вывод ставится блок с `clear:both`, на правый идет `float:right`, на левый `float:left`. То есть, Вам надо всего лишь изменить два стиля:  `#result{ float: right; clear: both; }` и `#output2 { float: left; }`. Но там еще желательно размеры margin-min выставить, посмотрите в инете двухколоночный сайт на блоках, тут две колонки так же делаются.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
#result {
    clear: both;
}

.block2 {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
```

P.S. Проверено только в FireFox.

Answer (score 0):

```
.block2 {
    display: inline-block;
    clear: both;
    float: right;
}   
.block3 {
    white-space: pre;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}
```

измените на:

```
.block2 {
    display: inline-block;
    /*или float: left; */
}
.block3 {
    white-space: pre;
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    /*или float: left; */
}
```

если используете `float`, добавьте код:

```
#result:after,
#output2:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]